# Getting a runtime error when running the test project

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, dll

I was running a test project which did execute without any problems. Then I added 2 extra DLLs and wrote some code as well. After that I got the below specified run time error. Though I removed those DLLs and new code still it doesn't run. This was running fine though. Please advice.

Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'Npgsql' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'g:\services\communityservice\communityservicetest\bin\release\communityservicetest.dll' was not found.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'IBM.Data.DB2' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'g:\services\communityservice\communityservicetest\bin\release\communityservicetest.dll' was not found.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'Oracle.DataAccess' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'g:\services\communityservice\communityservicetest\bin\release\communityservicetest.dll' was not found.

I have checked in the .csproj file. Those assemby references are not there

Comment: 1.Try to clean the Project and build it.and make sure you don't have the project running.

Comment: Yeah tried that. Still not working

Comment: Go to the bin-->Debug folder(Assuming you are in  Debugging mode) and check if you have communityservicetest.dll ?

Comment: Folder is empty. It is not getting created because of these missing DLLs. But it did work earlier!

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I don't think this is duplicate, because OP can't built the project even when he removed the references to particular libraries - different problem.